# Lubuntu: Errors launching apps from terminal

Tags: lubuntu, application

I'm a Linux newbie and just installed Lubuntu and installed a few application too. but when I'm running them through the terminal I'm getting an error.

When I start Firefox (which is pre installed) I don't get an error. But, when I run spotify:

> daniel@daniel-pc:~$ spotify
>   [1011/083525.086038:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped) Blockquote

And chromium:

> daniel@daniel-pc:~$ chromium-browser
>   [3594:3594:1011/084930.760942:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(369)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
>   [3594:3594:1011/084931.047206:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command                                                       (chromium-browser:3563): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 08:49:33.779: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed
>   ^C[3563:3577:1011/084941.998237:ERROR:browser_process_sub_thread.cc(203)] Waited 75 ms for network service 
>    Blockquote

Hope one of you can explain to me what is it all about, why it happens, and how to fix it.

edit:
Im using lubuntu 19.4 amd64

and i installed chromium from repository
and spotify from the guide on the site but I think somehow i skipped one of the steps and it still installed fine. the programs work just fine though

Comment: Please tell us how you installed Spotify and Chromium-browser, by clicking on [edit] and aading your answers to the original question. Also, which version of Lubuntu are you using?